# What is a "pseudo mannequin"?

Tags: terminology, product-photography, models

I am applying for a clothing store at Amazon and they are telling me pictures cannot be on a mannequin or a ghost mannequin, rather they should be on a real model or a *pseudo mannequin*.

What is the difference between the ghost mannequin achieved by editing the images and a PSEUDO mannequin? Anyone ever heard of this "pseudo mannequin" concept?

Comment: Have you contacted Amazon to clarify what they mean by "pseudo" mannequin? It's a good question with no immediate answer from the usual sources but I think Amazon are probably the best people to clear this up for you.

Comment: Amazon gave me an example of a Pseudo Mannequin: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HZESDHG to me this looks like a ghost mannequin!

Comment: here's a link that'll give you background on the technique: http://www.removethebackground.com/blog/ghost-mannequin-photography-1/

Comment: Hard to tell, but in the sample shot there appears to be a wire frame across the back. Perhaps it's a wireframe mannequin, but not being sure, I can't really supply it as an answer. I don't think I've ever heard that term before...

Comment: Just opinion/guess, but I think it's just a terminology issue. Ghost mannequins for photography are different from ghost mannequins for display; ours have removable bits to make the post-processing mannequin removal easier and tend to be much more expensive, but the garment trade version is mostly just a dress form that's really hard to stick pins into and will show at necklines, etc. Amazon seem to be saying "we want real people or nothing at all; we don't want to see any rigging".

Comment: @user38275 I think that seems like an educated guess as to their intention.

Answer (score 1):

Searches for "pseudo mannequin" return many pages in French. Aside from that, it may be a made-up phrase or something specific to Amazon.

#### Amazon Policy

The [2009](https://s3.amazonaws.com/merchant-facing/StyleGuides/ApparelStyleGuide.pdf) version of the Category Style Guide: Clothing & Accessories states:

> Do not use images where the product is shown with props, such as on a hanger, stand, or mannequin.

Both the [2014](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/ClothingStyleGuide.pdf) and [2018](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/SellerCentral/ClothingStyleGuide.pdf) versions state:

> Prohibited: Product images photographed on mannequin or digitally modified images

No mention of "pseudo mannequin", but even [Amazon is confused](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asellercentral.amazon.com%20mannequin) about its policies regarding images that may or may not contain mannequins.

#### Ghost Mannequins

Per @user38275:

> Ghost mannequins for photography are different from ghost mannequins for display; ours have removable bits to make the post-processing mannequin removal easier and tend to be much more expensive, but the garment trade version is mostly just a dress form that's really hard to stick pins into and will show at necklines, etc.

#### Other Mannequins

Those interested can read about [50 other types of mannequins](https://zenmerchandiser.com/mannequins/styles-types-of-mannequins/).